# Error: Cannot find module mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

Hi I am currently trying to write some unit tests using Mocha, however when I try to import one of my local modules it cannot seem to find it and spits out the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../communication/Model/RequestData'
```

This seems to happen with any of my local modules.

My Current directory goes as follows:

```
Lib
    src
        __tests__
            communication
                DataChannel.test.ts
        communication
            models
                RequestData.ts
            DataChannel.ts
```

My current tests import the following

```
import { assert, should } from 'chai'
import { describe } from 'mocha';
import { spy } from 'sinon';
import { IRequestData, RequestData } from '../../communication/models/RequestData';
import DataChannel from '../../communication/DataChannel';
```

Here is how I export my files:

RequestData.ts:

```
/**
 * @description Interface for request data
 */
export interface IRequestData {
    resource: string,
    data: any
}

/**
 * @class Model for request data
 */
export class RequestData implements IRequestData {
    public resource: string = '';
    public  data: any = null;
}
```

and here is my DataChannel.ts:

```
import { IRequestData } from "./models/RequestData";

/**
 * @class This class handles all data communication
 */
export default class DataChannel {
    /**
     * @constructor Constructor for the class
     */
    constructor() {

    }

    /**
     * @method Request Makes a request to the endpoint specified 
     * @public
     * @param data The data we are passing over to the endpoint
     */
    static Request(data: IRequestData): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this?